# Why my .speak is truncated in Android?

Tags: java, android

Why my speak is truncated?

```
private void speakOut() {
        String text = txtText.getText().toString();
        if (result != tts.setLanguage(Locale.US)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter right Words...... ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            // speak given text

            tts.s-p-e-a-k(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
    }
```

Is says:

```
'speak(java.lang.String,int,java.util.HashMap java.lang.String,java.lang.string>)' is deprecated
```

Comment: `deprecated != truncated`. deprecated = obsolete/don't use anymore. truncated = cut short.

Comment: Yes, its truncated in the word "speak". And when i place the cursor in the word say that is deprecated.

Comment: All ready function. The speak is deprecated but work. Thanks